# Install and configure virtualenv and python (Linux)

Tags: linux, python-2.7, ubuntu, virtualbox, virtualenv

I am doing it in Linux (ubuntu) in virtualbox.
https://github.com/blobmon/simplechan
On the above site

```
INSERT INTO boards (board, display_name) VALUES ('board 1', 'Board 1');
INSERT INTO boards (board, display_name) VALUES ('board 2', 'Board 2');
```

I did it to.
From that point on, I am planning to create a python virtual environment using virtualenv, but I can not.
First of all trying to install virtuallenv and python from normal state that have not moved

```
sudo apt install python 2.7
```

After entering

```
Reading package lists ... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information ... Done
python 2.7 is already the newest version (2.7.12-1ubuntu0 ~ 16.043).
0 upgrade, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 71 not upgrade.
```

And it was displayed in the same way in the case of virtualenv.
After that I would like to enter "cd simplechan / venv", move to the / venv file and set virtualenv there, but if you enter

```
$ virtualenv - python = / path / to / python 2.7.
```

When you enter this,

> The executable /path/to/python 2.7 (from - python = / path / to / python 2.7) does not exist

It will be displayed.
How can I do? By the way, install with "pip" command
I tried to do it, but I have no such command. It was displayed.
Also, python is 2.7 unless it is not good.

Answer (score 0):

1) Create a venv folder based on python 2.7 version (you don't need to specify python version if the default version is the one you need)

```
virtualenv -p python2.7 venv
```

2) Enter the virtual environment

```
source /venv/bin/activate
```

3) Install libraries from file requirements.txt

```
pip install -r /location/of/the/file/requirements.txt
```

Libraries should be installed now.

Comment: Thank you for nice advice!!